# Encoding/Decoding string containing Arabic characters in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, character-encoding

I am using a Spring Boot application to read message from a WebSphere MQ. The source system is sending the below String in Arabic in encoding ISO-8859-1:

```
امدرسة هوجورتس
```

The encoding at the queue manager is UTF-8 and I am receiving the below String from queue:

```
ÇåÏÑÓÉ çèÌèÑÊÓ
```

Can someone please guide me how can I get the Arabic characters from the String which is received by the application? I have tried to use the below code but it did not work:

```
String source = "اÇåÏÑÓÉ çèÌèÑÊÓ";
byte[] iso88591 = source.getBytes();
byte[] iso88596 = new String(iso88591, "ISO-8859-1").getBytes();
System.out.println(new String(iso88596, "ISO-8859-6"));
```

But I was able to get the Arabic character when I am using the online utility in the URL https://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx, encode with ISO-8859-1 and decode with ISO-8859-6

Comment: The source system can’t send send Arabic text as ISO-8859-1, as this encoding doesn’t have Arabic characters at all. Your receiving side is wrongly assuming the received bytes to be ISO-8859-1. Fix that instead of messing around with the wrong result.

Comment: I was able to get back the Arabic characters by using the above utility, selecting Encode with ISO-8859-1 and Decode with ISO-8859-6. I was trying to do the equivalent thing in Java so that I can get back the Arabic text.

Comment: The code above was pasted wrongly which I now fixed

Comment: This doesn’t matter. Your problem description is completely wrong. If you encode “امدرسة هوجورتس” with ISO-8859-1, you just get “?????? ???????”, as said, there are no Arabic characters in this encoding. This also implies that the statement that, whatever “the queue manager” is, used UTF-8 is also wrong as you can never get “ÇåÏÑÓÉ çèÌèÑÊÓ” from interpreting wrong bytes as UTF-8. And even if your kludges happen to produce something that look right, you should instead configure your queue manager to do the right thing in the first place, i.e. interpret ISO-8859-6 as ISO-8859-6 when receiving.

Comment: So will I try to change the encoding of the queue manager to ISO-8859-6 and try first?

Comment: I don’t know anything about your specific software, but generally, that’s what I said. Decode the bytes as they are received from the source using the right encoding. For completeness, the conversion you made at that website is equivalent to `new String("ÇåÏÑÓÉ çèÌèÑÊÓ".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "ISO-8859-6")`, but you shouldn’t do such conversions after the fact. It will lead to more problems in the future.

Comment: Ok thanks Holger, I will try that way and post again if there are problems

Comment: I did not read whether it already was stated that `String#getBytes()` uses the default platform encoding which is not portable. Holger specified the encoding in getBytes. Also note that browsers interprete ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) as Windows-1252 (MS Latin-1 with more symbols).  So you might use that instead to not miss some Arabic characters.

Comment: Sure, thank you Holger and Joop, will try the ways suggested

Comment: @JoopEggen Windows-1252 doesn't have any Arabic characters in it either.

Comment: @DavidConrad yes, the encoding is false. However ISO-8859-1 reserves the byte range 0x80 - 0xA0 for control characters, which just might corrupt a conversion mapping some char to a control. Whether that is the case I am unsure about. 0x85 is a NEL, newline character, originating indirectly from EBCDIC.